# RestKit : addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath produce extra record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I would like to use the `getObjectFromPath` method from RestKit to get data from my server. My testing server only has 3 records. After calling `getObjectFromPath` I assign them to an `NSMutableArray` to display on a `UITableView`.

I followed the RKMagicalRecord config and setup Core data locally.

However, everytime I run the app in the simulator, the number of records in the sqlite database grows like this

Number of time execute `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath` : number of records in sqlite

- 1st time execute `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath` : 0
- 2nd time execute `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath` : 3
- 3rd time execute `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath` : 6
- 4th time execute `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath` : 9

I have never use any saving method from Magical Record. As I google around, the `getObjectFromPath` method will do a mapping and then call the `success` callback block. During the mapping, it will auto-save Core Data.

But I don't understand why it did not save before execute `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath`. How can I disable the auto save in RestKit after mapping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not disable the auto-save. If you don't want object saved into the Core Data store then use plain `NSObject` subclasses.

That said, you should use Core Data, and what you're missing is probably setting the unique identifier key on the mapping (`identificationAttributes`). If you don't have unique identifier information coming from the server then you should add it. See [this example](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#configuring-a-core-data-object-mapping) entity mapping with `identificationAttributes`.

Calling `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath` creates the store the first time it's called and loads it on subsequent calls. So, before you call it there is no store so nothing can be added to it.